# Trying to learn how to render a character in blender that can have facial rigging

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I wanted to learn a little bit more about some resources I could look at when trying to create a human character model that has the capability for facial expressions/rigging.  It seems like every decent tutorial I watch on modeling lands me in a place where I can't even properly rig it without completely messing up everything.

I've been trying to figure out where to start for a long time, or what tutorials to watch but I can never seem to piece out what I need and end up frustrated and back where I started.

Comment: Asking for resources is considered off topic here, see [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender). Please reformulate your question to focus on the specific part of the workflow your are stuck with and why you can't advance past that point

Comment: I don't know the best way to explain @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I feel like this has been something I have been struggling to learn for some time and is really blocking my progress.  I build a model that's somewhat decent up until I get to the face (usually following a tutorial).  When I go to try to rig it following another tutorial I find that it's impossible.  Usually I can get the eyes to move.  The mouth/jaw area will get displaced.  I think most tutorials I've followed have been for still images.  But I can't find any info on how to model a decent character and rig it for animation.

Comment: Essentially @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I feel like I'm constantly hitting a roadblock and I don't understand what exactly it is that I'm even doing wrong in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried looking into actual production assets? Blender official demo files at the [Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org) are high quality production files made by proven professionals, you'll also get access to tutorials and libraries plus you'd be helping the foundation with a small subscription.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This might actually help a lot.  Would you recommend this over other subscriptions then?  I've been nervous about looking into them, in case they do not have the materials or answer the questions I have.

Comment: Don't take my word for it, I don't do character animation nor have I ever actually seen the materials available at the cloud; but given the "official" nature I'd expect a relatively decent degree of quality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: You could make a screenshot of your current specific problem, or even share your file, for example you say that when you rig your eyes the mouth get displaced, it must be because you haven't parented the eyes correctly. There are a lot of tutorials about rigging on youtube, but of course everyone has his own way to rig, it really depends on what you need and what is your character topology, etc...